# Issues with compilation of multiline lambdas

Tags: lambda, java-8

I'm looking at http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-java-streams-1-brian-goetz/index.html

Listing 6 doesnt seem to compile for me. I tried with an `ArrayList<Integer>` and ArrayList of objects.

```
int count = 
    anArrayList.stream()
               .map(e -> { System.out.println("Saw " + e); e })
               .count();
```

The error I get is:

```
The method map(java.util.function.Function<? super java.lang.Integer,? extends R extends java.lang.Object>) in the type Stream<Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (java.util.function.Function<? super java.lang.Integer,? extends R extends java.lang.Object>)
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Which (version of) compiler did you use when it answered "is not applicable"? All compilers I tried correctly answer by reporting a syntax error.

Comment: yes it's a syntax error. The '..is not applicable..' is the hint shown by my IDE (eclipse) . Probably should have mentioned that. :)

Comment: Lesson learnt: always attend to syntax errors first before wondering about semantic analysis like type checking :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
.map(e -> { System.out.println("Saw " + e); e })
```

to

```
.map(e -> { System.out.println("Saw " + e); return e; })
```

and it should work.

The contents of the curly brackets is a function, and syntactically must "return" it's return value. The semicolon is not optional.

This appears to be a typo on the website. 
Also note that in "real" code, you wouldn't want to include a side effect like System.out.println in the middle of your stream processing.